# Filter returns empty listview

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am trying a search/filter app where data are coming from mySql database to fill up the listview. The populating of listview is working perfectly fine, except for the filtering part. It doesn't filter the listview, it's empty. Help please.

MAIN Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String url = "";
    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();
        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
        editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        // Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayListView() {
        // Creating volley request obj
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(String json) {
        JSONArray items = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            rank = new String[items.length()];
            country = new String[items.length()];
            population = new String[items.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = items.getJSONObject(i);
                rank[i] = jo.getString("rank");
                country[i] = jo.getString("country");
                population[i] = jo.getString("population");

                WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(rank[i], country[i],
                        population[i]);
                // Binds all strings into an array
                arraylist.add(wp);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BASE Adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    mContext = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}

@Override
public WorldPopulation getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation());

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("rank",(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank()));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("country",(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry()));
            // Pass all data population
            intent.putExtra("population",(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation()));
            // Pass all data flag
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    worldpopulationlist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
    }
    else
    {
        for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist)
        {
            if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the model:

```
public class WorldPopulation {
    private String rank;
    private String country;
    private String population;

    public WorldPopulation(String rank, String country, String population) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public String getPopulation() {
        return this.population;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0/raw/10aa5bc585d97596485bdc714fb8e13b199fff3a/MatchableArrayAdapter.java) generic adapter

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I fixed it after I transferred `adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);
list.setAdapter(adapter);` after the loop in the parser